# Variable Compilation Symbols in C# .NET possible?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, hudson

We're using Hudson and msbuild.exe to build C# software, and I know it's possible to define (effectivly boolean) compilation symbols (as DEBUG or SOMETHING). I would like to have a value in my code that is defined while compiling the project, imagine an affiliate string or a personalised key or something like this. Something that can be used in the C# code.

Is this really not possible? If it isn't possible with compilation symbols, how would you approach this problem? Or is this so obvious that I just didn't see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to add a string to the compilation symbols in C# and there is no equivalent of C(++)'s #define.

The best thing to do is to add a file to your project that has a single constant defined in it. During compilation update the file to have the value you want. You can do this using the [WriteLinesToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164305.aspx) task in MSBuild.

Comment: You might want to add, since the OP was hinting at it, that using the C# preprocessor [#define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) directive it is not possible (in contrast to say C/C++).